# Runing pentaho command from a scheduler (tidal)

Tags: pentaho, tidal-scheduler

I am trying to execute the pentaho job over the windows through TIDAL, but the TIDAL does not execute the job at all. But when i run seperately on CMD PROMPT is executes.

The below is command used, IT does not the read the parameters assigned to it.
Kindly suggest on what has to be done.
E:\apps\Pentaho\data-integration\kitchen.bat /rep:Merlin_Repository  /user:admin /pass:admin /dir=wwclaims /job=J-CLAIMS /level:Basic

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a slash in `/dir:` option and you must use `:` not `=` symbols in your command.

For example in a windows batch script command

```
@echo off    
SET LOG_PATHFILE=C:\logs\KITCHEN_name_of_job_%DATETIME%.log    

call Kitchen.bat /rep:"name_repository" /job:"name_of_job" /dir:/foo/sub_foo1 /user:dark /pass:vador /level:Detailed >> %LOG_PATHFILE%`
```